# From crossword to confectionery

Tags: crosswords

I made a crossword, but this is no normal crossword!

Here's the grid:

[image]

And here are the clues:

```
24 grains, or 1/20 of a troy ounce
Acrophobia is the fear of this
An interconnected system
Foolish
Holding of office or land
Imaginary or unreal
Intermediary floor
Juvenile felines
Longest side on a right-angled triangle
Passionate
Past
Pointed tooth
Sheen or lustre
Susceptible
The first to explore unseen territory
Unstable oxygen
```

Once you solve it, can you give me the name of the thematic **confectionery** the crossword hints to?

---

### Clarifications

- Yes, these are all words used in English. Most of them are commonplace.

Comment: Ooh, that's clever!

Comment: @xnor But you didn't upvote?

Comment: I don't really understand.  There are no spaces long enough for "hypotenuse"?

Comment: Absolutely fantastic question, meticulously constructed, wish I could upvote 20 times! This is exactly the kind of thing that makes Puzzling.SE great. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Great puzzle! It was fun to solve the whole way through.

I found the key realization from the clue "Longest side on a right-angled triangle". The answer is clearly

> HYPOTENUSE, which is too long to fit

But, it can be made to work if you

> treat the substring "TEN" as the single number "10", putting that number in a single cell of the grid. The idea is to replace a substring with its number.

Solving for other clues the same way gives the answers:

> `24 grains, or 1/20 of a troy ounce      PENNYW8
> Acrophobia is the fear of this          H8S
> An interconnected system                NE2RK
> Foolish                                 ASI9
> Holding of office or land               10URE
> Imaginary or unreal                     N1XIS10T
> Intermediary floor                      MEZZA9
> Juvenile felines                        KIT10S
> Longest side on a right-angled triangle HYPO10USE
> Passionate                              IN10SE
> Past                                    BYG1
> Pointed tooth                           CA9
> Sheen or lustre                         SHI9SS
> Susceptible                             PR1
> The first to explore unseen territory   PI1ER
> Unstable oxygen                         OZ1`

and the grid

> [image]

Finally, we extract by

> reading the highlighed letters, which anagram to "SUM" and "ROWS"

This tells us to

> find the sum of the numbers in each row, which gives letters:
>
>
> `8+8=16     P
> 1+2+1+1=5  E
> 10+10=20   T
> 9          I
> 1+10+9=20  T`

Finally, this gives the answer

> [Petit four](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petit_four), from the clues that it's a confectionery and the theme of including a number in the word.

How did you make this? The whole thing seems really really constrained. I can't imagine there's many words to choose from, and the sums seem very restricting along with the intersection requirements.

Comment: Wow! Brilliant question and answer.

Comment: If you're looking for words that fit a certain pattern, [OneLook](http://onelook.com/) is a very useful tool. The set of numbers I could use was essentially `1 2 8 9 10`, which made five (E) very restrictive, requiring at least three clues (although the `2` words aren't very good, so it ended up being four). Then it was a matter of fiddling with the words for an hour trying to get them to fit in the grid, and when I couldn't join the last one on I expanded the grid by one.